# Why C function strlen() returns a wrong length of a char?

Tags: c, string, strlen

My C codes are listed below:

```
char s="MIDSH"[3];
printf("%d\n",strlen(&s));
```

The result of running is 2, which is wrong because char s is just an 'S'.

Does anybody know why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Because a char is not a string

Comment: @Ryan yes. he can use `sizeof(s)` instead.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's actually quite an interesting question. Let's break it up:

```
"MIDSH"[3]
```

String literals have array types. So the above applies the subscript operator to the array and evaluates to the 4th character 'S'. It then assigns it to the **single character variable** `s`.

```
printf("%d\n",strlen(&s));
```

Since `s` is a single character, and not part of an actual string, the behavior is undefined for the above code.

Comment: OK, the problem is that I didn't realize the difference between a single character and a char array. Thanks for your patient explanation to an inexperienced C programmer like me.

Answer (score 8):

Signature of `strlen` is:

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
/* The strlen() function calculates the
   length of the string s, excluding the
   terminating null byte ('\0'). */
```

`strlen` expects the input `const char array` is null terminated. But when you pass the address of an `auto` variable, you can't guarantee this and thus your program has an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> Does anybody know why and how to solve this problem?

`sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. So use `sizeof` or `1`.

Answer (score 6):

The statement

```
printf("%d\n",strlen(&s));
```

make no sense for the given case. `strlen` expects a null terminating string, `s` is of `char` type and `&s` need not necessarily point to an string. What you are getting is one the result of undefined behavior of the program.

To get the size of `s` you can use `sizeof` operator

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(s));
```

Answer (score 4):

The `strlen` function treats its argument as a pointer to a sequence of characters, where the sequence is terminated by the `'\0'` character.

By passing a pointer to the single character variable `s` you effectively say that `&s` is the first character in such a sequence, but it's not. That means `strlen` will continue to search in memory under false premises and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

when you use 
"char s=" you create a new address on the stack for 's',and this address can't be add or reduce!so though you give strlen a char* but it can't find '\0' by add address.All is wrong.
you should use strlen with a address for char which is a array.like:

```
char* s = "MIDSH";
printf("%d\n", strlen(s)); //print 5
s++;
printf("%d\n", strlen(s)); //print 4
```

Comment: The return type of `strlen()` (`size_t`) is not certainly compatible with `"%d"`.  Use `"%zu"`.